# ASP.net check box label name from xml

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, checkbox, datasource

I have a check box in an asp.net webpage

How to fill the labek name of the check box from an xml file ?

I did the same for dropdown but i want similar to checkbox

```
xmlData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("./App_Data/view1_" + txt_dropDownToLoad + ".xml"))
DropDownName.DataSource = xmlData
DropDownName.DataValueField = "ddl_cod"
DropDownName.DataTextField = "ddl_itm"
DropDownName.DataBind()
```

Comment: Are you want to populate checkboxlist?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Text` property of the `CheckBox` :

```
myCheckbox.Text = "value from Xml"
```